# How to unpivot an unknown number of columns in Google Dataprep / Trifacta?

Tags: unpivot, google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta

Trifacta / Google Dataprep allows one to unpivot data, using its [Unpivot Transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Unpivot-Transform_57344656) operator, in which one specify which columns to unpivot at design stage.

How could one say unpivot an unknown number of columns.  Here is a data example:
[image]

The unpivot should start from column '1/22/20', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to unpivot all columns by using a wildcard `*`.

[image: unpivot - wildcard]

Note that it is also possible to specify a range of columns (e.g. `Column1~Column20`).

[image: unpivot - range]